# Displaying text with html tags as html

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework

I am trying to display a text file as html. I am using ionic.
I am sending a response that is in html format but in a text file to profile page. Its in the variable name in the .ts page.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-profile',
  templateUrl: 'profile.html',
})
export class ProfilePage{
  name: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    this.name = navParams.get('name');
```

Now I am trying to display it in in html format using

```
<div [innerHtml]="name">{{name}}</div>
```

But I get it in text format and not html. How to display in html format?

Comment: post the `name` values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [DomSanitizer](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer#bypassSecurityTrustHtml) to bypass html which you provided(bypassSecurityTrustHtml).

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
            public navParams: NavParams,
            private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {

  this.name = sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(navParams.get('name'));

}
```

Read more here: https://angular.io/guide/security#bypass-security-apis